# Extract vectors from LDA2vec model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, lda

I want to implement lda2vec and extract vectors then feed them to the ml classifier. I tried to implement  https://github.com/TropComplique/lda2vec-pytorch but I failed.
 I got this error No such file 'model_state.pytorch' when I run explore_trained_model.ipynb
can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll probably have more luck getting an answer if you explain what you tried and what errors it gave.

Comment: Thank u for the response. when I run explore_trained_model.ipynb ,exactly when i run this code " state = torch.load('model_state.pytorch', map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)" I got this error 'No such file 'model_state.pytorch' , I didn't arrive to fix it.

Comment: The comments are **not** the right place for such info; please edit & update your post with the *exact* coding issue you are facing, otherwise your question will most probably be closed as "too broad" or even "unclear what you're asking".